# How to fund Ethereum address relatively anonymously? (breaking a link with an already established address)

Tags: privacy, anonymity, faucets, shapeshift

I want to deploy smart contract.

I just don't want people inspecting the code on Etherscan to see what crappy ICOs I've sent my ETH back in 2017...

---

Some options coming to mind:

- use Shapeshift
- withdraw ETH from an exchange with high volume
- use a mixer: https://www.privcoin.io/ethereum/
- use faucet, solve some captchas, get "free" ETH, any amount should be sufficient to deploy the contract *(set very low gas price)*

---

Via: https://www.bloomberg.com/features/2017-the-ether-thief/

> But where did the original money to fund the attack come from? To interact with the ethereum blockchain, every contract must be funded by an amount of ether. This attack contract was funded by two addresses, but tracing it further back becomes tricky. That’s because the second address used an exchange called ShapeShift to send 52 ether into its account on June 14. ShapeShift doesn’t collect any information on its users and says it turns one virtual currency, such as bitcoin, into another, like ether, in less than 10 seconds. While there are valid reasons for using ShapeShift, it’s also a great way to launder digital assets and cover your tracks.

Chances are I'll send some Monero (XMR) to ShapeShift. Any better ideas?

Comment: Any ideas why law enforcement / community didn't ask ShapeShift to provide funding address? Any ideas if DAO hack was actually reported to the police - did attacker break the law, or just used undocumented feature? I remember 2016 at Boom Festival and discussing with my friend - decision that will take place now is likely to affect the future for millennia to come. Just like recent visit to Liberland for 3rd anniversary of the most economically liberated country.